# Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Computational Science Stack Exchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Done. Copy/pasting the key words into Google, and the results are in general much better than last several self-eval I have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Minimisation problem in thousands of dimensions](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14513/minimisation-problem-in-thousands-of-dimensions)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Books and references on implementing finite difference codes for PDEs](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14485/books-and-references-on-implementing-finite-difference-codes-for-pdes)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Exascale computer today](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14477/exascale-computer-today)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Speedier alternative to “skimage.morphology._pnpoly import points_inside_poly”?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14474/speedier-alternative-to-skimage-morphology-pnpoly-import-points-inside-poly)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [When are two vectors considered "close"?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14585/when-are-two-vectors-considered-close)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Parallel Gram-Schmidt algorithms](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14545/parallel-gram-schmidt-algorithms)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [optimising changing the range of integers from random number generation](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14613/optimising-changing-the-range-of-integers-from-random-number-generation)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Lax-Richtmyer stability analysis](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14578/lax-richtmyer-stability-analysis)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Should I pass command line arguments to MPI_Init or not?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14637/should-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-mpi-init-or-not)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is there a jump condition for this PDE? ( Brinkman model , piecewise constant permeability)](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/is-there-a-jump-condition-for-this-pde-brinkman-model-piecewise-constant-pe)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Answer (score 2):

I am not talking about rating, but only some of my feelings. I feel so empty visiting this site `Computational Science Stack Exchange`. Whatever downvotes there will be, I don't care about it.

First, I want to share an experience about comparison between `here` and `Quora`. I posted a question on `Quora`, closed that site. Then I found a similar but different question. I came `here` to ask that one. What happened? The first question answered, and I got a positive respond. What about the second one? `ON HOLD` to be deleted by an admin, saying "to general to be answered". Then I deleted that. I still cannot handle that one until I try to forget that question. `Quora` is more open to people, but in `here`, we are afraid to be punished. Then the audience left. But I have to confess that the idea of creating this site is excellent. And there ARE great people here, as far as I know. What is the problem?

Second, I find that there would be no news(almost no) in one day. Still most of these questions I cannot handle. I don't even care. And what I am curious about cannot find the right guy to answer me. I don't mean the answers are bad, they are really good. Sometimes I find they are not answering in my way of wanting to know. Mostly because I don't know how to ask?

Yes, you can say my answer is **OFF TOPIC**. But that is what I am worried about this precious site.